# How to acquire memory consumption information in Java

Tags: java, memory, tasklist

I am new to Java. I want to retrieve the memory consumptions of different running Java programs. For example, I write the following program variations,

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld2{
public static void main(String[] arr){
System.out.print(" HELLO WORLD in Java P2");
List<Integer> container=new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for(int i=1;i<=500000;i++)
 {
      container.add(i);
 };
    }
}
```

I variate the range of i by magnitude of 10s, run the programs from command line to see how the memory consumption changes accordingly.

But I find it difficult to see such memory consumption in the windows task list. Any ideas for me to read it from Java platform?

Thank you indeed,

best

Comment: One option is to perform a heap dump with Visual VM.

Comment: Ideally a heap dump should give the details of the memory. 
Decent resource: https://visualvm.github.io/gettingstarted.html